# How to Hide Progress Dialog from another Fragment - Android

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-fragmentactivity

I have three tabs (using Fragments/ViewPager/SupportLibrary/FragmentActivity).

The left tab uses a ProgressDialog on initial load.  But I default to the center tab.  Yet when I first enter this Activity and land on that center tab, the ProgressDialog from tab #1 shows on tab #2 (center).

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I prevented this using booleans. I don't think it's a very clean way though. Simply set a boolean on true when the tab is selected and execute the asynctask only when the tab is selected.

So in my MainActivity I have a array of 3

`public static boolean[] selected = new boolean[3];` (static have to do with external classes I use might not be needed in your case)

I indicate each tab with a description

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        if (tab.getContentDescription() == "tab1")
        {
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);   
            selected[0] = true;
            selected[1] = false;
            selected[2] = false;
            mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (tab.getContentDescription() == "tab2")
        {               
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
            selected[0] = false;
            selected[1] = true;
            selected[2] = false;
            mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (tab.getContentDescription() == "tab3")
        {
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
            selected[0] = false;
            selected[1] = false;
            selected[2] = true;
            mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

In fragment:

```
    if (MainActivity.selected[0])
    {
               // asynctask fragment
    }
```